# Combine 2 nested objects together preserving properties from both while adding duplicate keys values together

Tags: javascript

I have seen several posts about merging two objects together but most of them are for merging objects containing objects that do not contain nested elements. And when I implement one of the suggested solutions, properties form one object is overwritten.

```
const Gnome = () => {
  return {
    ExpRate: .20,
    Abilities: {
      PickDoors: 1,
    },
    Buffs: {
      NightSight: 65, 
      MagicRes: 5, 
    },
    ... Additional data and behaviors
  };
}

const Thief = () {
  return {
    ExpRate: 2.10, 
    Abilities: {
      Thievery: 1,
      PickDoors: 1, 
    },
    Buffs: {}, 
    // ... Additional data and behavors
  };
}
```

I've been trying to merge the two objects to look like:

```
{
 ExpRate: 2.30,
 Abilities: {
    PickDoors: 2,
    Thievery: 1
 }, 
 Buffs: {
    NightSight: 65,
    MagicRes: 5, 
 }, 
// ... Additional data and behavors from both objects
};
```

However using Object.assign will overwrite values in existing keys, losing the data.  IE:

```
const myGnome = Gnome();
const myThief = Thief();
const myPlayer = Object.assign({}, myGnome, myThief);
```

I have tried some of the suggested merge methods people have posted, but they all seem to have the same behavior as Object.assign();
Any suggestions would be appreciated.  If this is in fact a repeated post, I'd love the link to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should write a recursive function on your own to handle this task.

Comment: @Timothy McCune what would happen if the `ExpRate` is a `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the entries and check if an object is found then call the function again for nested object. If numbers are found add this values.

```js
function merge(a, b) {
    function mergeTo(source, target) {
        Object.entries(source).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (Array.isArray(v)) {
                target[k] = target[k] || [];
                target[k].push(...v);
                return;
            }
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
                mergeTo(v, target[k] = target[k] || {});
                return;
            }
            if (typeof v === 'number') { 
                target[k] = (target[k] || 0) + v;
                return;
            }
            if (!(k in target)) {
                target[k] = v;
                return;
            }
            target[k] = Array.isArray(target[k])
                ? [...target[k], v]
                : [target[k], v];
        });
    }

    var object = {};
    mergeTo(a, object);
    mergeTo(b, object);
    return object;
}

console.log(merge(
    { ExpRate: .20, Abilities: { PickDoors: 1 }, Buffs: { NightSight: 65, MagicRes: 5 }, array: [1, 2], v: 'a' },
    { ExpRate: 2.10, Abilities: { Thievery: 1, PickDoors: 1 }, Buffs: {}, array: [3, 4], v: 'b', f: true }
));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What will happen if the value is `string` or `Boolean`

Comment: actually nothing, the get filtered out. maybe the value should be collected in an array. but op should answer this question, i think.

Comment: This approach works great! Even when adding the Behaviours of each object (ie: a pickDoors() method to both objects).  The idea is to have several races with specific abilities and buffs and professions with abilities.  some race/profession combinations may share the same skill.  If a race/profession combination contains the same skill definition, they are added to an array, avoiding duplicate functions within the object.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using **Recursion**. Below is the example

```js
const Gnome = () => {
  return ({
    ExpRate: .20,
    Abilities: {
      PickDoors: 1,
    },
    Buffs: {
      NightSight: 65, 
      MagicRes: 5, 
    }
  });
}

const Thief = () => {
  return ({
    ExpRate: 2.10, 
    Abilities: {
      Thievery: 1,
      PickDoors: 1, 
    },
 Buffs:{}
  });
}
let thief = Thief();
let gnone = Gnome();




function merge(obj1,obj2){
 let keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
 let keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
 let objToReturn = Object.assign({},obj1,obj2);
 let sameKeys = [... new Set(keys1.filter(key => keys2.includes(key)).concat(keys2.filter(key => keys1.includes(key))))]
 sameKeys.forEach(key => {
  if(typeof obj1[key] === "object") objToReturn[key] = merge(obj1[key],obj2[key]);
  else objToReturn[key] = obj2[key] + obj1[key];
 })
 return objToReturn;
 
}
console.log(merge(thief,gnone));
```

Comment: Thanks for the post.  This works great until I introduce some behaviours to each object.  IE:  adding a sneak method to the thief works fine but if I were to add a  PickDoor method to both objects, then the merge won't produce the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  I will give your suggestions a go.  I was able to write a function, as suggested:

```
    function isObject(item) {
      return (item && typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item));
    }

    function mergeDeep(target, source) {
      let output = Object.assign({}, target);
      if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
        Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
          if (isObject(source[key])) {
            if (!(key in target))
              Object.assign(output, { [key]: source[key] });
            else
              output[key] = mergeDeep(target[key], source[key]);
          } else {
              if(typeof target[key] === 'number' && typeof source[key] === 'number'){
                  source[key] += target[key];
              }

            Object.assign(output, { [key]: source[key] });
          }
        });
      }
      return output;
    }
    console.log(
      mergeDeep(
        {ExpRate: .20, Abilities: {PickDoors: 1}, Buffs: {NightSight: 65, MagicRes: 5}}, 
        {ExpRate: 2.10, Abilities: {Thievery: 1, PickDoors: 1}}
    ));
```

I will give the other suggestions a go since I'm worried the above approach may get a bit convoluted and lead to issues in the future.